# Parsing Matlab Matrix in C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a `MWCellArray` object that appears as follows in code (using DLL integration):

```
MWCellArray movieResults = (MWCellArray) RecommendationResults[0];

int[] dim = movieResults.Dimensions;

MessageBox.Show("rows: " + dim[0].ToString() + " colums: " + dim[1].ToString());

MessageBox.Show(movieResults.ToString());


MessageBox.Show(movieResults[1][20].ToString());
```

The Matrix is 2 dimensional with `dim[0] = 3` and `dim[1] = 3`. ToString() on the full object returns:

[image]

The first dimension in the last line seems to capture the rows correctly, but the second dimension seems to capture the individual characters of the first column. Here I would expect indexing 20 to fail since we only have 3 columns, so my question is how then do I process the output? The documentation from MatLab is rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

A little workaround. You can implement a function to get matrix elements in MatLab:

```
function x = getmatrixelement(A, r, c)

[Rows, Columns] = size(A);

if ((r <= Rows) && (c <= Columns))
   x = A(r, c);
end
```

Then from C# you can fill an Array or process the results directly:

```
MWCellArray movieResults = (MWCellArray) RecommendationResults[0];

int[] dim = movieResults.Dimensions;

for (int row = 1; row <= dim[0]; row++)
{
    for (int column = 1; column <= dim[1]; column++)
        MWArray[] results = recommender.getmatrixelement(1, movieResults, row, column);

        MWCellArray cell = (MWCellArray) results[0];

        MessageBox.Show(cell.ToString());
    }
}
```

Note `recommender` is an instance of the class supplying the `getmatrixelement` function. This can readily be adapated for numeric MatLab arrays.

Comment: could you please explain about the recommender getmatrixelement method?